# Android Studio not creating a flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

When I press the "create new Flutter Project" button in Android Studio, it just creates a regular java project, where I can't even use dart code. I can still run flutter doctor in the terminal on the project, but that's it. It doesn't create an actual flutter project. I have flutter installed, flutter doctor doesn't show anything wrong, and I have the flutter and dart plugins installed.

I don't know what's causing it, but I did have to reinstall android studio because of storage space, and I recently updated it to giraffe. I have tried reinstalling flutter and restarting my PC, but neither worked.

[image: What my android studio looks like]

EDIT: To the people saying "Maybe this will help: New Flutter project -> Flutter -> Next" in the comments, please read the very first sentence of this question.

Comment: You are able see *create new Flutter Project* I hope you did installed flutter extensions.

Comment: Yes, the button is there and the extensions are installed. The button just doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Comment: can you try by restarting your  computer

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Randall When you click the "Create new Flutter Project" button you also see the "Flutter" and "Dart"  below in the sidebar. Could you please check Flutter and Dart SDK paths? It would be nice if you could share the screenshot of them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

New Flutter project -> Flutter -> Next

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Read the first sentence of this question.  "When I press the "create new Flutter Project" button in Android Studio"

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

Step 1 : [image]

Step 2 :  [image]

Step 3 : [image]

And you are done.

Comment: "When I press the "create new Flutter Project" button in Android Studio"